# Declaring a function with same signature of the given template parameter's function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp

I'm writing a wrapper class to be derived which hides the implementation. How can I get the signature of the given template parameter's function?

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
  static typename std::result_of<&T::impl>::type
  call(...) { // this function has the same signature of T::impl();
    // here goes the jobs to do, such as logging or something
    return T::impl(...);
  }
};

struct sum : public wrapper<sum>
{
private:
  friend class wrapper<func>
  static int impl(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
  }
};

int main()
{
  bind_to(&sum::call); // set binding
  std::cout << sum::call(1,2,3) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the `struct sum : wrapper<sum>` line supposed mean?

Comment: @Mikhail: that is inheritance

Comment: A struct is inherited from a template class, specialized with the struct itself?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes. It's CRTP

Comment: @kukyakya Very cool! However, don't you think this advanced pattern distracts from the real question you were asking?

Comment: @BЈовић Would you elaborate to explain that? I thought friend part is needed since `impl()` is a private function.
@Mikhail The example is too much simplified, but there are some more jobs to do in `wrapper::call()`. I'm creating a binding to another language, so I think this is the only way, otherwise I need to Copy-and-Paste the jobs in `wrapper::call()`.

Comment: ok, you are right. private is needed

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter pack:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
    template <typename... Args>
    auto call(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T::impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return T::impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I know that forwarding the arguments does the job, but I need the  function pointer to `call()`, which is not possible with perfect forwarding.

Comment: this doesn't even compile

Comment: This compiles for me. So you have C++11 enabled?