# typedef return type of template parameter's member function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm trying to `typedef` the return type of a member function of a template argument. So something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class DoSomething{
    typedef return_type (T::*x)(void)const data_type;
    data_type x1;
};
```

In this case, I want to `typedef` the return type of a const member function of the template parameter, called `x`. In this example `return_type` is just a place holder, just to show what I want. It won't compile.

EDIT:
The reason I want it this way is: I want to do the operations on x1 or any other variable of type `data_type` in this example, with the same precision as the return type of the x() member function. So if x() returns a float all my template ops will be in floats and so on.

I found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643989/declaring-a-function-with-same-signature-of-the-given-template-parameters-funct) on SO. But I don't want to use any C++11 features. So no `decltype`, no `auto`. Just something that will work with a C++03 compiler.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Are `return_type`, `x`, or `data_type` declared anywhere previously?  Can you show an example use of `x1`?

Comment: Many compilers have the compiler specific extension `typeof` that more or less does the same as `decltype`. Also C++11 solves so many problems, preferring to hack around problems instead of just using the standard solution is ridiculous.

Comment: @nwp It's likely not about personal preference, but about external constraints one cannot affect. Please learn to distinguish the two before disrespecting others and making this site a less pleasant place to read.

Comment: @user4815162342 It says "I don't want to use any C++11 features" in the question. What I meant to say is that it is worth reconsidering that opinion. "I am not allowed to use any C++11 features" is a totally different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work (even when Boost Typeof is forced to use the long way rather than any C++11 or compiler-specific feature):

```
#include <boost/utility/declval.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>

template <typename T>
class DoSomething {
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL(boost::declval<T const&>().x()) data_type;
    data_type x1;
};
```

But the resulting type cannot involve any class, struct, union, or enum types.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this may be boost's typeof, which operates like decltype, but works in C++03.

Answer (score 0):

The core idea of the typedef is the following:

```
typedef known_type [<modifiers>] new_type;
```

In this case `known_type` should be already defined and known. Dot. There is not other way. Based on this known existing type you can define a new type.

Start thinking from this.